# Execution of clojure tests from Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, clojure, intellij-idea, jenkins

I'm working on a Java project that contains clojure tests. These tests are executed using the "Clojure Maven Plugin: https://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin

I've executed the tests at local (from the IntelliJ IDE) successfully, but when I try from Jenkins I get the next error. Any idea?

```
message : Failed to execute goal com.theoryinpractise:clojure-maven-plugin:1.3.13:compile (compile) on project smartsteps-dsp-qa: Clojure failed.
cause : Clojure failed.
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.theoryinpractise:clojure-maven-plugin:1.3.13:compile (compile) on project smartsteps-dsp-qa: Clojure failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:100)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:66)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Clojure failed.
    at com.theoryinpractise.clojure.AbstractClojureCompilerMojo.callClojureWith(AbstractClojureCompilerMojo.java:446)
    at com.theoryinpractise.clojure.AbstractClojureCompilerMojo.callClojureWith(AbstractClojureCompilerMojo.java:362)
    at com.theoryinpractise.clojure.AbstractClojureCompilerMojo.callClojureWith(AbstractClojureCompilerMojo.java:339)
    at com.theoryinpractise.clojure.ClojureCompilerMojo.execute(ClojureCompilerMojo.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 27 more
```

The related content of the pom.xml is:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
                <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.13</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectories>
                            <sourceDirectory>src/main/clojure</sourceDirectory>
                        </sourceDirectories>
                        <testSourceDirectories>
                            <sourceDirectory>src/test/clojure</sourceDirectory>
                        </testSourceDirectories>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Adding verbose flag I get this error message

EDIT:Adding verbose flag I get this error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.lang.Compile
```

Comment: There's not much information to go on in that stack trace. I recommend increase the logging of maven via the debug switch (-X,--debug). You may then get some information (output prior to the stack trace) on why the clojure plug-in is failing.

Comment: @MarkVedder I've added the debug flag and I get a previous error message in the stack trace. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify clojure as a dependency. Add the following to your pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
        <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

BTW, the plugin configuration you have is just repeating the defaults. This should be sufficient:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
    <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.17</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```